# How to read PDF files in VB.net or convert PDF to word document in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, ms-word

I need to read text in a PDF with an application written in VB.net.  What is currently the best way of doing this.  I am also open to first convert the PDF to a word document and read that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextPdf looks like a good starting point, open source and c# so any examples should be portable to vb.net
The c# port
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/

The site
http://itextpdf.com/

alternativly take a look at this article for a number of .net alternatives 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx

Comment: thanks, for the info.  Porting itextsharp to vb looks time consuming though (unless porting tools are really reliable at doing this) I think I will either use the DLL with the vb app or make a small program in cs and call it from my vb app.