# c# manipulate doc and save as pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, doc

I have been reading a lot of questions about convert doc files to pdf but I haven't read any response which solve my problem.

I tried ASPOSE, which is really good for what we want but it is really expensive and my boss doesn't want to spend a lot of money.

I need to open a docx file, manipulate it and save as pdf. My boss doesn't want the system save the file as docx and then convert to pdf.

Anyone has a simple solution to do that?

### Thank you in advance.

PS: We have abcpdf and asppdf components but I didn't find any documentation about open a pdf file and save it as doc

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822859/how-to-read-pdf-files-in-vb-net-or-convert-pdf-to-word-document-in-vb-net

Comment: @AmenAyach  I read about IText but it doesn't convert word to pdf or vice-versa.

_I quote: iText can convert an XML or an HTML file to PDF, but only on a very basic level. Converting documents from one format to another is outside the scope of iText. **And no: iText does not convert Word documents to PDF!** ._

Answer (score 2):

If your boss wants to open a .DOC and save as .PDF then maybe Word or Word automation will help.

Newer versions of Microsoft Word are able to produce PDFs.

**EDIT**

Here are some links to sample code:

[How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/607669/249690) (see accepted answer)

[Word Doc to PDF Conversion. Command line using VBScript and automation](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/word2pdf.htm)

Comment: in this case we need to install the office on the server machine to be able to use the interop. But How can I do that? Do you have any code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iTextSharp to read the content and manipulate it then use openxml sdk to create word document from the read information.

Openxml SDK:

```
http://openxmldeveloper.org/
```

Comment: That is the problem, my boss wants to OPEN the .doc file manipulate and save as .pdf.
The .doc file is a template file, and I think it is too much things to do if I copy the file, open, change it, save and then convert from .doc to .pdf.

Comment: Store the templates in a table (as HTML).  This way it prevents those stupid users from making changes ;)

Comment: @cristiam: thought you wanted to convert pdf files to doc..."I need to open a pdf file, manipulate it and save as docx."

Comment: @Sam1 Thank you to tell me, I wrote wrong the question. Now it is fixed.