# Can I create a software which reads PDF files and creates folders?

Tags: pdf, basic

I want to create a software using visual basic which reads some text in a PDF file (name on an invoice), and then creates a folder using that name. Is this possible to do, and how would I get started on this? I have programming experience in the past.

Comment: Short answer? Yes.

Comment: Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822859/how-to-read-pdf-files-in-vb-net-or-convert-pdf-to-word-document-in-vb-net or perhaps here https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/extract-text-from-pdf

Answer (score -1):

PDFs are difficult to manipulate. To do it efficiently, you'd need some libraries that allow you to open the PDFs and extract the text from it.

I haven't used VB much, but I don't expect that there will be much support for PDFs.

You are probably better off using a language like [Python](https://www.python.org/), which has a lot of support for PDFs.

See for instance:
- http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=parse+pdf&submit=search
The first link also contains a few tutorials.

Comment: The .NET framework indeed has no native support for PDF, but there are numerous PDF libraries for .NET. Take a look at the Linked and Related Questions. I am downvoting your answer because the question was specifically for .NET (VB.NET to be precise, but any .NET library will do) and the question is answerable in that context. And has in fact been answered by Rickard B.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Cool. Didn't know VB was synonymous with .NET.

Comment: Visual Basic is only one of the languages in the .NET framework. Others are C#, F#, and yes even Python for .NET.